# Probability that 100 coins land on heads

Tags: probability

We flip infinitely many fair coins $1,2,\ldots$ independently.

We have a collection $H$ with infinitely many subsets of $100$ coins. We are interested in the probability $p(H)$ that in *at least one* of the subsets in $H$, all coins fell on heads.

There are two extreme cases.

**Case A**: $H$ contains $M$ pairwise-disjoint subsets. The probability that a single subset is all-heads is $2^{-100}$, and all subsets are independent, so $p(H) = 1-(1-2^{-100})^M$. In particular, if $M\to\infty$ then $p(H)\to 1$.

**Case B**: All subsets in $H$ have a common intersection of size $N<100$. Then, $p(H)$ is (at most) the probability that this common intersection is all-heads, which is $2^{-N}$. In particular, if $N=99$ then $p(H) \leq 2^{-99}$.

MY QUESTION IS: What characterizes the collections $H$ for which $p(H)\to 1$? Is Case A (infinitely many pairwise-disjoint sets) the only case or are there other cases?

Comment: what probability space are we using?

Comment: Each coin has a probability of $1/2$ to be heads, independenetly of all other coins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(H)$ is $1$ if and only if there is no finite subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $h\cap S \neq \varnothing$ for all $h\in H$.

Clearly if such a set $S$ exists then $P(H)<1-2^{-|S|}$.

Suppose that no such $S$ exists, then we can construct a family of disjoint elements of $H:h_1,h_2,\dots$ recursively.

To do this pick $h_1$ arbitrarily, after this, suppose $h_1,h_2,\dots,h_n$ have been selected, notice that $h_1\cup h_2\dots\cup h_n$ is a finite set, so it does not satisfy the condition we asked of $S$, therefore we can pick an $h_{n+1}$.

Using your case $A$ we are done.

Comment: Beautiful proof. Thanks!